# Does the large number of sample is the reason for low p-value in GOF test of Copula? (Cramer_Von mises)

Tags: sample-size, goodness-of-fit, copula

I would like to determine a suitable copula function on my data.

The multivariate computed from the original data is similar to the Plackett.

[image]

The GOF test on my data with size 8000, reject all copula functions (e.g., Gumbel, Frank, Clayton, Normal, Plackett, tCopula and etc.).

gofCopula(plackettCopula(),pobs(data, ties.method = "random"), estim.method="itau",simulation = "mult")

I was wondering if this rejection is because of the large size of my data? 
If not, why non of the copula functions are not suitable for my data?

Comment: The short answer is that your data are not perfectly described by any of the copula families you have tested.  They are by no means "all" possible copulas.

Comment: Your data seems mixture data. You need to use mixture copula.